# Why do I get the iteritems deprecation warning in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, deprecation-warning

Whenever I try to do anything with .loc or .iloc in pandas, I get a FutureWarning/Deprecation message. In addition, every command I type into the console after this (correct or not) results in the same warning. This continues until I reset the console. I am using Python 3.9.6

The following is an example of what I try to do and the error message I received:

```
movie_ids = z.loc[:,'tmdb_id']

/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_utils.py:606: FutureWarning: iteritems is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use .items instead.
  for item in s.iteritems():
```

Comment: '.iteritems()' is now just '.items()'

Comment: @OriYarden But what does .iteritems have to do with .loc ?

Comment: .iteritems() returns an iterator of the dictionary’s list in the form of (key, value) tuple pairs which is a Python v2.x version and got omitted in Python v3.x version.


.items() returns a copy of the dictionary’s list in the form of (key, value) tuple pairs, which is a Python v3.x version, and exists in Python v2.x version.

Comment: have you tried to upgrade pandas? that should help

Comment: Upgrading pandas worked! Thank you Joe Ferndz.